# ASP.NET: disable endpoint not found page or redirect when requesting non-existing endpoint

Tags: asp.net, web-services, url-rewriting, endpoint, iis-8.5

I have this webservice URL: `http://www.example.com/service.svc/whatever`

Because that endpoint does not exist I get the a page with message:

> Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing
>   valid requests to the service.

How can I disable that page? Or even better: redirect to an error page?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a custom error in your web.config you can make that page redirect them to anywhere you would like or an error page you prefer.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Home/Error" />
    //Other web.config default settings
</system.web>
```

OR alternatively, if you want specific pages for specific errors:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

and so on, for each code.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I know which error was triggered? I want to have a specific error for approaching a non-existing endpoint and not for example when a 404 or other error is triggered. How would I do that?

Comment: @Flo you can follow this exact method, and if you want specific pages for specific errors its just a matter of writing it this way: 
```<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html"/>
</customErrors> ``` (edited answer to reflect)

Comment: @FernandoRodriguez: thanks. I already had this in my web.config file, but it does not trigger a redirect to the 404 page: `    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error/1" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>`

Comment: Your code is not the same as the code in the example...I think your default always takes over..

Comment: @FernandoRodriguez: sorry, forgot to add, it does redirect non-existing .aspx pages, e.g. requesting `http://www.example.com/foo.aspx` redirects to `http://www.example.com/404?aspxerrorpath=/foo.aspx`...however, requesting `http://www.example.com/foo` (so extensionless), does *not* redirect to the custom page. How can I solve that?

Comment: You can do this directly in IIS if you wanna direct a specific page somewhere else https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324000